# How to disable the search filtering option in Magento store

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento2

In my magento store I would like to disable the filtering option from the left pane (see attachment below). I don't want the filtering option to be there. How could I achieve that through admin panel?

I would appreciate if anyone could help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the admin Panel : 
1- go under Catalog => Categories 
2- choose category 
3- In the "Display Settings" section disable "Anchor" :

[image]